# encodeURIComponent() Lowercase

Tags: javascript, jquery, encodeuricomponent

In JavaScript, I want to use `encodeURIComponent()` but the output is in uppercase.

```js
console.log(encodeURIComponent("[Abcd123]"));
//returns %5BAbcd123%5D
```

I want to have a lowercase result like

```
%5bAbcd123%5d
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Why do you want that? What do you hope to achieve?

Comment: What about .toLowerCase() on a string

Comment: @AtanasB - That would change the non-encoded `A` to `a`, which they appear not to want.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Not possible. Why? %5B refers to [ not %5b ... 
  Refer for more details: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP

Comment: I want to match it as lowercase

Comment: @AlaksandarJesusGene - No, the hex digits of percent encoding are not case sensitive.

Comment: @AlaksandarJesusGene not hard to check: `console.log(unescape("%5b"), decodeURI("%5b"))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regexp to convert the two characters after `%` to lowercase.

```js
console.log(encodeURIComponent("[Abcd123]").replace(/%../g,  match => match.toLowerCase()));
```

Comment: I am getting `%5bAbcd123%5D`, the `%5D` is in uppercase

Comment: I forgot the `g` modifier

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed!